# Can django-comments handle multiple comment forms on the page?

Tags: django, forms, django-comments

I have multiple models on a Django-powered webpage that have a django.contrib.comments form rendered for each.  On this page, a post from one of these forms to `/comments/post/` always results in:

```
Forbidden (403)
CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.
```

If I include the same comment form code on another page where there is just one such form, it posts just fine.

Also fyi, I have included `'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware'` in the MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES and the `{% csrf_token %}` inside the comment form.

Any thoughts on this error or getting multiple django-comments forms on a page submitting correctly?

Comment: does every of those forms has different prefixes? Also does @csrf_exempt making the view work?